# Find number of occurrences in different variables

Tags: r

I have a data frame with some data about different people. They look like this:

```
Year Item ID
2005   a   1234
2005   b   1234
2005   a   4567
2005   b   4567
2006   a   4567
2006   a   7894
```

My data has 45000 observations and about 1000 different ID's and 10 different years. I want to find the ID's of people that appear in more than 1 year, how do i do this? I thought of separating the data by ID and seeing if the resulting data has different years, but that doesn´t seem like the smartest way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` the `Year` by `ID` and then keep only those sub-groups that have more than one unique `Year`

```
list1 = lapply(split(df1$Year, df1$ID), unique)
list1 = list1[lengths(list1) > 1]
data.frame(ID = names(list1), count = lengths(list1))
#       ID count
#4567 4567     2
```

---

```
#DATA
df1 = structure(list(Year = c(2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 2006L),
                     Item = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "a"), ID = c(1234L, 1234L, 4567L, 4567L, 4567L, 7894L)), 
                class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA,  -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` we can use `n_distinct` and get only those `ID`'s which have more than 1 year.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Year) > 1) %>%
  pull(ID) %>%
  unique

#[1] 4567
```

---

A base R alternative with `table`

```
unique(df$ID)[rowSums(table(df$ID, df$Year) > 0) > 1]
#[1] 4567
```

Answer (score 1):

We can get the duplicated IDs and then get those duplicated within these:

```
Dups<-df[duplicated(df$ID),]
 Dups[duplicated(Dups$ID),]["ID"]
 # ID
 # 5 4567
```